# Cannot define a function out of slinalg.ExpmGrad in Theano

Tags: gradient, theano

I'm trying to use the [`ExpmGrad`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/slinalg.html#theano.tensor.slinalg.ExpmGrad) function built in in Theano.
However, when I define a `theano.function` out of the `ExpmGrad` I get an error saying that the outputs must by theano variables.

I'm not sure on what exactly should be the correct way to use this `ExpmGrad` function as I didn't find any examples of its usage online.

This is what I tried:

```
import theano
from theano.tensor import T
J1 = T.dscalar('J1')
H = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4) * J1
gJ = theano.tensor.slinalg.ExpmGrad(H)
f = theano.function([J1], gJ)
```

and this is the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-122-2e2976e72a77> in <module>()
      4 # gJ = theano.gradient.jacobian(H[0], J1)
      5 gJ = theano.tensor.slinalg.ExpmGrad(H)
----> 6 f = theano.function([J1], gJ)

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/compile/function.py in function(inputs, outputs, mode, updates, givens, no_default_updates, accept_inplace, name, rebuild_strict, allow_input_downcast, profile, on_unused_input)
    318                    on_unused_input=on_unused_input,
    319                    profile=profile,
--> 320                    output_keys=output_keys)
    321     # We need to add the flag check_aliased inputs if we have any mutable or
    322     # borrowed used defined inputs

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py in pfunc(params, outputs, mode, updates, givens, no_default_updates, accept_inplace, name, rebuild_strict, allow_input_downcast, profile, on_unused_input, output_keys)
    440                                          rebuild_strict=rebuild_strict,
    441                                          copy_inputs_over=True,
--> 442                                          no_default_updates=no_default_updates)
    443     # extracting the arguments
    444     input_variables, cloned_extended_outputs, other_stuff = output_vars

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py in rebuild_collect_shared(outputs, inputs, replace, updates, rebuild_strict, copy_inputs_over, no_default_updates)
    225                 raise TypeError('Outputs must be theano Variable or '
    226                                 'Out instances. Received ' + str(v) +
--> 227                                 ' of type ' + str(type(v)))
    228             # computed_list.append(cloned_v)
    229     else:

TypeError: Outputs must be theano Variable or Out instances. Received ExpmGrad of type <class 'theano.tensor.slinalg.ExpmGrad'>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExpmGrad` is not a function, it's a subclass of `theano.Op`. "Calling" the class will just create a Op instance, not the result you want.

To use it properly, you should instantiate the Op as a functor to make use of it:

```
expm_grad = theano.tensor.slinalg.ExpmGrad()
gJ = expm_grad(H, gw)
```

For the above code, you need to properly define `gw` argument, which is the upstream gradient.

Note: the gradient op is normally not designed to be used directly, it's recommended to use `theano.grad` to indirectly use it

```
J1 = T.dscalar('J1')
H = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4) * J1
expH = theano.tensor.slinalg.expm(H)
e = some_scalar_function(expH)
gJ = theano.grad(e, J1)
f = theano.function([J1], gJ)
```